# Is there a way to run multiple SQL queries at the same time in R?

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I have 3 queries that takes a long time to run. Each of them takes around 40 minutes to run and running them one by one takes around 2 hours. I am curious to know if there is a way to run the 3 queries at the same time so that it takes around 40-50 minutes to run all three of them.

I can run all three queries in SSMS and it usually takes 50 minutes to run all of them concurrently.

So I am just wondering if I can make the query process concurrent.

Thank you in advance. I really appreciate any insight on this.

Comment: If you have queries taking 40 minutes the problem is the query. I think a better approach would be to fix the queries.

Comment: @Ringtail , you can set 3 different jobs on sql agents, and run them concurrently if they are not depended. You just trigger jobs to start on your procedure, so it will only start jobs and finish

Comment: just a guess, open 3 r sessions and run each query in each of them and see what happens? then save the files and call in whatever script you need them for. If you need to run the queries all in the same session this won't work.

Comment: @SeanLange I query health system data which spits 1.5 GB of data. Please don't jump into conclusion.

Comment: @RingtailLemur fair enough but 1.5GB isn't all that huge. Poorly worded on my part but with queries running that long my first step would be analyze the query and see what can be done to make it faster.

Comment: can you share you queries so we can help and see if it can be optimized?

Comment: @Mike The problem is I join the three queries together and perform some data analysis for COVID 19 reporting. So I need to have them in the same session.

Comment: @Mike The SQL query has 2,011 lines of code. Most of them to figures out comorbidity, smoke, alcohol use, past hospital visits, vaccination information... all sorts of stuff. It's indeed complex. I also have to make sure that it doesn't involve anything that would give away Personal Health information.

Comment: ok fair enough, I would say there is multicore processing that might help speed up the job but I have never used it myself. additionally you can schedule a job about 2 hrs before you need the data (or when you start work) and have the session ready to go

Comment: @RingtailLemur take a look at the package `future` I use it for when I want to do an asynchronous API pull. I more often use `libray(future.apply)`
 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-1-overview.html

Comment: The parallel package comes with R so you don't even have to install it - just use library(parallel) and read the vignette.  Also there are CRAN packages discussed in https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Comment: If your queries are IO bound (as opposed to CPU bound) its highly unlikely running them in parallel will speed them up. As mentioned, you may want to optimize them first so they don't take so long anyway. At a guess, 2000 lines of codes is probably full of slow things like `WHILE` loops and cursors, and could probably be heavily optimized.